# Python, loops and closures

Tags: python, function, closures, definition

I'm a fairly experienced C/C++ (and to some degree, Java) programmer. I'm learning python, but I'm baffled at some strange (for my backgroung) behaviors of the language.

I'm learning about nested function and closures (reading "Learning Python", that seems a really good source for me).

I understand that if I nest a def inside a for loop when I call the created function, it looks up the last value of the captured loop variable (as it captures by reference, as a C++ programmer would put it)

```
funcs = []
for i in range(4):
    def f():
        print(i)
    funcs.append(f)
```

and running the program the result is

```
>>> for f in funcs:
      f()


3
3
3
3
```

Now, I was wrapping my head around this when I stumbled upon this (what to me seems) an inconsistency: if I do

```
for i in range(4):
  funcs[i]()


0
1
2
3
```

more baffling, if I do

```
>>> i = 2
>>> funcs[i]()

2
```

and now, all functions in list returns 2:

```
for f in funcs:
  f()


2
2
2
2
```

there must be some scope related question that I can't grasp

Comment: Your first posted code does not work as you expect it to since the indentation is wrong.

Comment: sorry, it's a copy-paste error, my code is right, editing it now

Comment: I think you've messed up the indentation on `funcs.append(f)`. I might be out of sorts here, but `print(i)` will print the last `i` generated. In your case, that's `for i in range(4):` and not when you defined the function. So it's not strange that you're gettnig that output. So `i` isn't frozen upon function creation, but it's a live value. You're printing the last known/set value of `i`.

Comment: If I run the program as you edited it now the output is just one '3'...

Comment: Neither can I reproduce the second example. Please fix the indentations and write complete code so we can help you!

Comment: @mrCarnivore what's wrong with the indentation? it's just one statement block with one level indentation

Comment: @Torxed the append() call is inside the for loop as I need to create a list of function objects

Comment: @Luca Yea sure. I edited your question before you edited it three times in a row because I assumed that was the case. Never the less. `print(i)` won't print the `i` from the `def f()`-loop, but rather the `for i in range(4): funcs[i]()`-loop. See my comment above.

Comment: Although the answers below already said it all, you might want to check out the explanations [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) and [here](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-the-sticky-output-function).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, this creates a list of four functions.

```
funcs = []
for i in range(4):
  def f():
    print(i)
  funcs.append(f)
```

Each of these functions looks up the value of `i` and then prints it.

This loops through the list of function and calls each one:

```
>>> for f in funcs:
      f()
```

As stated above, these functions look up `i`, which is 3 right now due to the `for i in range(4)` loop that completed earlier, so you get four printouts of 3.

Now you loop again, using `i` as the loop variable:

```
for i in range(4):
  funcs[i]()


0
1
2
3
```

The first time through the loop, `i` is 0, so when the function looks up `i`, it gets 0, and then prints that. Then it changes to 1, then 2, then 3.

The following code simply changes `i` in yet another way, and calls a function:

```
>>> i = 2
>>> funcs[i]()

2
```

You could've called any of those functions and they still would've printed 2, because that's the value of `i` now. You're just getting lost because you looped over `range(4)` to create these functions, then you looped over `range(4)` to index the list of functions, and you keep reusing `i`, and then you reassign `i` and also use it to index the list.

If you want each function's printed value of `i` to be fixed at what it was when you defined the function, the easiest way to do that is with a default argument, as those are evaluated when the function is defined rather than when it's called:

```
funcs = []
for i in range(4):
  def f(num=i):
    print(num)
  funcs.append(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, this is an alternate implementation:

```
def getfunc(i):
    return lambda: i

funcs = []
for i in range(5):
    funcs.append(getfunc(i))

for item in funcs:
    print(item())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your functions

```
def f():
    print(i)
```

print the current value of `i`.

If you write

```
for i in range(4):
    funcs[i]()
```

then `i` is being set to `0,1,2,3` as you go through the loop. That's what `for i in range(4)` means.

If you write

```
for f in funcs:
    f()
```

then `i` continues with whatever value it already had.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inconsistency here. The value of `i` in `f()` depends on  the value of `i` from the parent scope. After you've run the first `for i in range(4)` `i` has the value of the last item in the `range`, which is 3, and thus all subsequent calls to `f()` will print 3

If you run

```
for i in range(4):
  funcs[i]()
```

you redefine the value of `i` at each iteration step, and so you get `0,1,2,3` as the values printed by `f`. Doing

```
for x in range(4):
   funcs[x]()
```

will not affect the value of `i` and so you'll get `3` as the value of `i` in all function calls

Answer (score 1):

take some time for me to understand, actually in this example,

You will find `f.__closure__` is `None` if you `print` it, ie. nothing related to closure, it's just about procedure the undefined local var `i` look for its value:

it can't find its value in local scope, finally find it in global scope (like python MRO)