# generating functions in a loop using variables from the loop cause shadowing effects of variables

Tags: python, variables, scope, composition

I want to generate small functions in a loop that access variables from the loop. Then I want to compose and apply the functions all at once. An MWE looks lie this:

```
from functools import reduce

def compose(*funcs):
    return lambda x: reduce(lambda y, f: f(y), reversed(funcs), x)


def replace_values_by_type(text, values, types) -> str:

    def peek(x):
        print('peek:', x)
        return x

    replacements = [lambda txt: peek(peek(txt).replace(peek(val), f'<{peek(typ)}>')) for val, typ in zip(values, types)]
    replace = compose(*replacements)

    text_with_replacements = replace(text)

    print(values)
    print(types)
    print(text)
    print(text_with_replacements)
    print()

    return text_with_replacements



replace_values_by_type('this is a test sentence', ['is', 'test'], ['A', 'B'])
```

When I run this I expected to get "this <A> a <B> sentence". But Only the last pair of `val` and `typ` from the loop actually are used.  So I guess some shadowing or overwriting happens. Can you explain this?

```
-> % py mwe.py 
peek: this is a test sentence
peek: test
peek: B
peek: this is a <B> sentence
peek: this is a <B> sentence
peek: test
peek: B
peek: this is a <B> sentence
['is', 'test']
['A', 'B']
this is a test sentence
this is a <B> sentence
```

Btw. to isolate the issue I also wrote the function like this:

```
def replace_values_by_type(text, values, types) -> str:

    replacements = []

    for val, typ in zip(values, types):
        def f(txt):
            return txt.replace(val, f'<{typ}>')

        replacements.append(f)

    text_with_replacements = text
    for f in replacements:
        text_with_replacements = f(text_with_replacements)

    return text_with_replacements


print(replace_values_by_type('this is a test sentence', ['is', 'test'], ['A', 'B']))
```

The problem remains the same.

Comment: I think the list comprehension just establishes a single scope for the iteration variables, there isn't a scope for each iteration.

Comment: @Bramar So they get overwritten each iteration then, huh? I tried to use deepcopy on `val` and `typ` inside `f`, because I suspected that. But that did not help either.

Comment: There's nothing to copy. The issue is the uses of the variables `val` and `typ` -- all the lambdas refer to the same variables, and they contain the last values from the loop.

Comment: In JavaScript this is called the "infamous loop issue". I'm trying to find similar questions about Python.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288926/python-loops-and-closures

Comment: Is there any elegant solution to create the `f` closures that fix the values of `val` and `typ` as they were when `f` was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the closures created by the list comprehension are in the same variable scope, and there's just a single instance of the `val` and `typ` variables for the loop. When the closures are called later, the variables have their values from the last iteration.

You need to generate the closures in a unique scope for each iteration. One way to do this is to write a separate function that returns the closures, since every function establishes a new scope.

```
def replacer(val, typ):
    return lambda txt: peek(peek(txt).replace(peek(val), f'<{peek(typ)}>'))

replacements = [replacer(val, typ) for val, typ in zip(values, types)]
```

Comment: Ah, I understand, thank you very much.