# Python lambda functions not working with loops

Tags: python, loops, lambda

```
li = []
for i in range(5):
    li.append(lambda: i)

for item in li:
    print(item())
```

This code results in the function always returning 4. Why is this happening exactly and is there anyway to prevent this while keeping the same idea for the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, loops and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288926/python-loops-and-closures)

Comment: @NickParsons Although the question is partially answered by the question you are pointing to, `is there anyway to prevent this` is not completely answered.

Comment: @Tarik I think the last paragraph that says _"If you want each function's printed value of i to be fixed at what it was when you defined the function, the easiest way to do that is with a default argument"_ gives an example on how it can be prevented?

Comment: Fair enough. I added an alternate implementation in there. Will vote to close this question.

Comment: The last value of i set is 4. So, when that function is called, it is not returning the number it was originally inputted with, but rather just 4.